# Is there any function for opening a preview (peek) with a long press gesture since 3D Touch won't be supported in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

I want users to have the peek & pop functionality which was supported on iPhone 6S and newer but implemented with long press gestures since this is what Apple itself is implementing in iOS 13 by removing 3D Touch on the new iPhones. Are there already some functions and delegates available or is this something that will come with the new Xcode version?

Implementing a long press gesture isn't a problem but the delegates where pretty handy which Apple provided with 3D Touch.

Comment: Can you specific which parts of UIKit you mean? The documentation in `https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH4-SW1`points to the current developer pages, and the "Deprecated" stuff is liked to the replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [UIContextMenuInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction) is what you're looking for. Example tutorial [here](https://kylebashour.com/posts/ios-13-context-menus).

Answer (score 0):

Using SwiftUI, you can also do a `.contextMenu(menuItems:)` to get a context menu using long press.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-a-context-menu